# Changes of web.xml are not reflecting when trying to run the project on tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I have created a simple web based project in which  i defined one `jsp` file as the welcome file in `web.xml`.

`<web-app>

    <welcome-file-list>
         <welcome-file>welcome.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>`

I have also created the `welcome.html` file in `web-content` folder.The project ran fine on `tomcat7`.

Now I have changed the `web.xml` to declare the `index.jsp` as the default file

`<web-app>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>`

I have created the `index.jsp` in `web-content` folder.But still the browser is showing the same welcome.html.I have clean the project.I have also tried with creating a new instance of the server.But everything is in vain.I have also tried to open the URL in the chrome as well but it is showing the `HTTP 404` error.

Comment: Can you include the full `web.xml` in your question ? Something else in there (e.g. servlet mappings) may be interfering.

Comment: there is nothing else has been declared in web.xml. Actually in some other project I faced this issue . so I just created a dummy project , to check , will it reflect the same issue or not .

Comment: Strange, this should work. Did you try to clear the content of Tomcat's "work" directory (where JSP files get compiled) ?

Comment: Also try to clear your browser cache, just in case.